# Trying to log an .exe and get error message "UniPaas cabinet file (ecf) does not exist" and "abnormal termination" can not open ecf file

Tags: logging, dll, exe, ini, magic-unipaas

I am trying to troubleshoot a 3rd party UniPaaS / Magic software. The program uses simple serial protocol to communicate with another machine using com ports. I am getting the error "user function/procedure not found/loaded" when on the screen that uses the DLL in order to communicate with the other machine.

I have tried to run "C:\Documents and Settings\Admin\Desktop\Setup.exe" /L*V "C:\Program Files\test.txt" and I get the error message "UniPaaS cabinet file (ECF) does not exist" and "abnormal termination: can not open ECF file"

I tried running the .exe through Dependency walker but for some reason, I cannot log the profile to the point I get the error message.

I am needing to find the cause of the error message in the program. I have 2 basically identical PC's and the software will run on one PC just fine but not the other. So far, I have come up with nothing in regards to finding out why this software does not work on certain PC's.

Any point in direction would be appreciated!

Tried Dependency Walker hoping to find a DLL not working but am unable to profile through the .exe

Tried running log script through the command line, but get ecf errors

Tried creating a custom viewer in event viewer, but no luck.

Edit** When I say 3rd party, I mean it's my employer's software but it was contracted out to be written using uniPaaS, which I am unfamiliar with.